# Архитектура Клиент-Сервер

Tags: клиент-сервер, архитектура, java

Такая предыстория: клиент и сервер обмениваются по одному сообщению, серверу нет смысла хранить список всех клиентов, т.е. с каждым ведется отдельная работа. Сервер, по сути, выполняет работу с БД и выдает данные каждому клиенту в зависимости от запроса клиента. Так вот у меня такой вопрос: "Что будет меньше загружать сервер: содержать поток, который будет слушать запросы клиента и отвечать на них, до тех пор, пока клиент не отключился, или убивать поток и сокет после каждого ответа на запрос пользователя и создавать снова при подключении пользователя? "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ зависит от коркретной ситуации. При выборе надо иметь в виду следующее:

- как часто клиенты выполняют какие-то действия, т.е. время простоя
- надо ли иметь возможность слать клиенту сообщения
- насколько критична задержка из-за пееподключения

Ясно, что если клиент часто делает какие-то запросы, то если каждый раз переподключаться, то затраты на подключения могут вырасти. А главное при таком подходе производительность может сильно упасть из-за того, что подключение требует времени как минимум порядка двух-трёх пингов, а иногда и больше. Так что если клиент будет часто переподключаться, то вы проиграете.

Поддержание соединения в активном состоянии требует памяти. Если включён keep-alive, то периодически надо ещё посылать его и принимать, обрабатывать таймауты.

В большинстве случаев всё же предпочтительнее держать соединение открытым пока не случится какой-нибудь таймаут, пока соединение не оборвётся или количество соединений не превысило какое-то значение, а соединение не использвалось какое-то время. В общем, есть несколько статегий на этот счёт.

**UPD**

Имейте в виду ещё две вещи: количество открытых сокетов в системе ограничено (в том числе количеством локальных портов), и если соединений с keep-alive будет жутко много, то могут возникать лаги в сети. Поэтому я рекомендую сделать следующее:

- установить для себя некий лимит на количество соединений
- держать неактивные сокеты в какой-нибудь очереди в порядке последнего обращения, и при необходимости закрывайте самое старое неиспользуемое
- опционально можно закрывать сокеты, которые не используются в течение T минут (выбирайте константу по обстоятельствам)

Comment: Спасибо! В принципе обмен сообщениями происходит не часто, поэтому я вообще задумался о том, чтобы закрывать потоки. Клиент шлет запросы, когда ему нужна какая-то информация из БД на сервере, как-то так. Решение я нашел, Java NIO. Т.е. сами сокеты я буду держать открытыми, но вот больше тратиться на потоки не придется, т.к. там обработка событий предусмотрена, т.е. если кто-то хочет подключится, открывать на него сокет, если кто-то отправил запрос, то обработать запрос и ответить на него и т.п. Т.е. мне не нужно кормить много потоков, которые будут сидеть и ждать, когда клиент что-то спросит.

Comment: Только при стратегии с закрытием старых соединений по инициативе сервера надо иметь в виду, что клиенты должны правильно реагировать на это, а не считать, что сервер "упал".

Comment: @avp спасибо, учту

Answer (score 1):

Опять тема про сферического коня в вакууме.

Попробуйте реализовать сначала один подход, потом если не устроит - реализуйте другой подход. Я когда на C# реализовывал сервер бизнес-логики, Я использовал **асинхронные сокеты**. Судя по тому, что было написано в статье, из которой Я эту информацию подчерпнул, это был довольно производительный вариант, который смог бы обслужить до 4000 соединений. В Джаве наверняка что-то подобное есть.

Comment: Это я понял. Я знаю как это реализовать, мне просто было интересно знать что дешевле: кормить поток, пусть даже ожидающий команды клиента, или тратиться на то, чтобы снова инициализировать сокет, открыть in\out потоки и т.п.